# Unminified SoundCloud SDK

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I want the unminified SoundCloud SDK. It has an error that doesn't show up anywhere on Google nor here, so I want to debug it myself, but cannot because the minified JavaScript is nigh unreadable.

I found this:

https://github.com/soundcloud/sc-connect/

I downloaded the whole SDK and tried using latest.js... and then tried http://connect.soundcloud.com/latest.js, but I'm getting errors that SC.initialize doesn't exist. If I go back to sdk.js, no problem. I'm a js n00b so I'm sure it's something simple.

Comment: Did you try http://jsbeautifier.org/?

Comment: No, but while I still can't read the code, that allows me to debug a lot easier, thanks! It'd still be nice to debug some normal code; is this normal for JavaScript development to not include un-minified versions of code?

Comment: For proprietary software, unfortunately, yes. For open-source development, obviously the source code is available.

Answer (score 4):

Our Javascript SDK's repository is now public on http://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-javascript. Additionally there is http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.unminified.js.